# What is the most efficient way to store a set of points (embeddings) such that queries for closest points are computed quickly

Tags: information-retrieval, embedding, word-embedding, data-retrieval

Given a set of embeddings, i.e. set of [name, vector representation]
how should I store it such that queries on the closest points are computed quickly. For example given 100 embeddings in 2-d space, if I query the data struct on the 5 closest points to (10,12), it returns   { [a,(9,11.5)] , [b,(12,14)],...}

The trivial approach is calculate all distances, sort and return top-k points. Alternatively, one might think of storing in a 2-d array in blocks/units of mXn space to cover the range of the embedding space. I don't think this is extensible to higher dimensions, but I'm willing to be corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are standard approximate nearest neighbors library such as [faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss), [flann](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/), [java-lsh](https://github.com/tdebatty/java-LSH) etc. (which are either [LSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) or [Product Quantization](https://lear.inrialpes.fr/pubs/2011/JDS11/jegou_searching_with_quantization.pdf) based), which you may use.

The quickest solution (which I found useful) is to transform a vector of (say 100 dimensions) to a long variable (64 bits) by using the [Johnson–Lindenstrauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma) transform. You can then use Hamming similarity (i.e. 64 minus the number of bits set in **a** XOR **b**) to compute the similarity between bit vectors **a** and **b**. You could use the [POPCOUNT](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/POPCNT.html) machine instruction to this effect (which is very fast).

In effect, if you use [POPCOUNT](https://www.quora.com/What-is-__builtin_popcount-in-c++) in C, even if you do a complete iteration over the whole set of binary transformed vectors (long variables of 64 bits), it still will be very fast.